# Problems with german characters in MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Has anyone a solution to the following problem:
When I want to display a string in a StringElement that contains a german Umlaut like: ä,ü or ö or an ß it is shown as a white questionmark in a black-filled rectangle.
Any suggestions how to solve this are highly appreciated!

Comment: Found a solution to this. However regarding it as a hack!

Comment: Found a solution to this. However regarding it as a hack! If I pull my strings from the localizable.strings file in my project's de.lproj folder there is no problem with showing umlaut characters, so I am converting umlauts in strings contain one to ae or oe and then I am getting the correct character from the localizable.strings file via an extension method. As written above I am considering this solution as a hack and if there are better ones I would be very happy to learn about them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this. However regarding it as a hack! If I pull my strings from the `localizable.strings` file in my project's `de.lproj` folder there is no problem with showing umlaut characters, so I am converting umlauts in strings contain one to ae or oe and then I am getting the correct character from the `localizable.strings` file via an extension method. As written above I am considering this solution as a hack and if there are better ones I would be very happy to learn about them...